# How to acquire the Viper armor?

Tags: the-witcher-3

During the Auction house quest of the Heart of Stone expansion I encountered an old lady collecting everything Witcher related. I can't remember her name, but she was a countess.

During the conversation I had the option to buy the Viper armor from her, but I didn't because I wanted to fulfill her task first. After completing the task she became unavailable. I could not start a conversation with her.

Will I have another chance to buy the Viper armor or was this my only chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buying the armor from the countess in the auction house during the Open Sesame quest is the only way to get the Viper school diagrams.

The swords are available elsewhere.

Comment: That is bad news... Maybe I will load an earlier save game and lose a few hours of gameplay. I think it was a bad decision, especially because she has other dialogue options, that, if chosen first, prevent you from buying the diagrams.

Comment: Note that the steel viper sword can only be found, there is no diagram for it. Of course, you have to look for it when you are under time pressure -- you will know when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a blueprint of Viper steel sword outside of the first starting area White Orchard, go to the cemetery.